# How do I connect existing mysql tables with fastapi?

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I want to create an api for login authentication. I have used the below method to create the table, but I don't want to create a new table but instead use an existing table.

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from database import Base, engine, SessionLocal

class User( Base ):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    items = relationship("Item", back_populates="owner")
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

SQLALCHEMY_DB_URL = "mysql://root:mumbaicity@localhost:3306/ryr"

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DB_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()
conn = engine.connect()
```

this is the table I want to use: (employee):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkO9g.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply not run `Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)` and define a class for the table you want.

If you have many tables and want to automatically generate model classes, look into [sqlacodegen](https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen).